# How to add containers to a Kubernetes pod on runtime

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a number of [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/)
running on k8s.

These jobs run a custom agent that copies some files and sets up the environment for a user (trusted) provided container to run.
This agent runs on the side of the user container, captures the logs, waits for the container to exit and process the generated results.

To achieve this, we mount Docker's socket `/var/run/docker.sock` and run as a privileged container, and from within the agent, we use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/tree/master/docker) to interact with the user container (setup, run, capture logs, terminate).

This works almost fine, but I'd consider it a hack. Since the user container was created by calling docker directly on a node, k8s is not aware of it's existence. This has been causing troubles since our monitoring tools interact with K8s, and don't get visibility to these stand-alone user containers. It also makes pod scheduling harder to manage, since the limits (cpu/memory) for the user container are not accounted as the requests for the pod.

I'm aware of [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) but these don't quite fit this use case, since we want to keep the agent running and monitoring the user container until it completes.

*Is it possible for a container running on a pod, to request Kubernetes to add additional containers to the same pod the agent is running? And if so, can the agent also request Kubernetes to remove the user container at will (e.g. certain custom condition was met)?*

Comment: k8's best practice suggests that pods should be immutable. however ephemeral containers can be used if needed. -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608785/how-to-add-a-docker-container-to-a-running-kubernetes-pod/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37838#issuecomment-328853094), it seems that the answer is that adding or removing containers to a pod is not possible, since the container list in the pod spec is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

**Original Answer**

<s>In kubernetes 1.16, there is an alpha feature that would allow for creation of ephemeral containers which could be "added" to running pods. Note, that this requires a feature gate to be enabled on relevant components e.g. kubelet. This may be hard to enable on control plane for cloud provider managed services such as EKS.</s>

[API Reference 1.16](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#ephemeralcontainer-v1-core)

[Simple tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/)

**Updated Answer**

Ephemeral containers are stable as of Kubernetes 1.25.

> Ephemeral containers are useful for interactive troubleshooting when kubectl exec is insufficient because a container has crashed or a container image doesn't include debugging utilities, such as with distroless images.

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/)

[Tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can alter a running pod like that but you can certainly define your own pod and run it programmatically using API

What I mean is you should define a pod with the user container and whatever other containers you wish and run it as a unit. It's possible you'll need to play around with liveness checks to have post processing completed after your user container dies

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between multiple containers in a pod using [shared volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/). this would let your agent container read from log files written on the user container, and drop config files into the shared volume for setup.

This way you could run the user container and the agent container as a Job with both containers in the pod. When both containers exit, the job will be completed.

You seem to indicate above that you are manually terminating the user container. That wouldn't be supported via shared volume unless you did something like forcing users to terminate their execution at the presence of a file on the shared volume.

> Is it possible for a container running on a pod, to request Kubernetes
>   to add additional containers to the same pod the agent is running? And
>   if so, can the agent also request Kubernetes to remove the user
>   container at will (e.g. certain custom condition was met)?

I'm not aware of any way to add containers to existing Job pod definitions. There's no replicas option for Jobs so you couldn't hack it by changing replicas from 0->1 like you potentially could on a Deployment.

I'm not aware of any way to use `kubectl` to delete a container but not the whole pod. See [kubectl delete](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_delete/).

If you want to kill the user container (rather than having it run to completion), you'll have to get on the host and use `docker kill <sha>` on the user container. Make sure to set `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never"` on the user container or k8s will restart it.

I'd recommend:

- Having a shared volume to transfer logs to the agent and so the agent can set up the user container
- Making user containers expect to exit on their own and read configs from the shared volume

I don't know what workloads you are doing or how users are making containers so that may not be possible. If you're not able to dictate how users build their containers, the above may not work.

Another option is providing a binary that acts as a command API on the user container. This binary could accept commands like "setup", "run", "terminate", "transfer logs" via RPC and it would be the main process in their docker container.

Then you could make the build process for users something like:

- FROM your-container-with-binary:latest
- put whatever you want in this
  container and set ENV JOB_PATH=/path/to/executable/code (or put code
  in specific location)

Lots of moving parts to this whichever way you make it happen.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the "agent" container is not really in control of the life-cycle of the "user" container. E.g., how would the agent "start" the user's container when the environment is ready, how would it terminate it, etc? The only mechanism, as you said is through files, but this requires you to expect "user" containers to handle this signals and voluntarily terminate, which doesn't seem a reliable approach. .

Comment: The agent container wouldn’t start the user container in this approach. The agent and user container would start at the same time and the agent container would signal the user container when it was ready to run the application inside the user container. Your original post doesn’t indicate what runs in the user container and how much (if any) control you have over that so I made a lot of assumptions. The application doesn’t have to run immediately upon container start if you have an init system or it can start immediately and wait until the files are in place to execute its logic.

Answer (score -1):

You can inject containers to pods dynamically via : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/

> An admission controller is a piece of code that intercepts requests to
>   the Kubernetes API server prior to persistence of the object, but
>   after the request is authenticated and authorized. The controllers
>   consist of the list below, are compiled into the kube-apiserver
>   binary, and may only be configured by the cluster administrator. In
>   that list, there are two special controllers: MutatingAdmissionWebhook
>   and ValidatingAdmissionWebhook. These execute the mutating and
>   validating (respectively) admission control webhooks which are
>   configured in the API.
>
> Admission controllers may be “validating”, “mutating”, or both.
>   Mutating controllers may modify the objects they admit; validating
>   controllers may not.

And you can inject additional runtime requirements to pods via : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/

> A Pod Preset is an API resource for injecting additional runtime
>   requirements into a Pod at creation time. You use label selectors to
>   specify the Pods to which a given Pod Preset applies.

Comment: your answer is little superficial, can you grant us more insight?